# MediaPlayer setDataSource failed with status=0x80000000

Tags: android, kotlin, uri

I keep getting this error when trying to play audio, here's what I'm doing and the values of the variables:

```
val audioFileUri = data.data!! //is of type Uri
audioFileUri = audioFileUri.toString() //to store it
val decodedUri = Uri.decode(audioFileUri) //using it later
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(decodedUri))
```

my audioFileUri:
`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AMusic%2FNewPipe%2F%5B2019%20FESTA%5D%20Euphoria.m4a`

my decodedUri is  `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Music/NewPipe/[2019 FESTA] Euphoria.m4a`

I get this error:

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: Unable to create media player
MediaPlayer setDataSource failed with status=0x80000000
```